Disable Safari suggestions in Spotlight
macOS 14.6.1.
System Settings > Siri & Spotlight > Siri Suggestions and Websites check boxes are turned off:

Nevertheless, if I open Spotlight and type "apple", I see this:


How to turn this off?
Do you have same issue?

I should add that in the "System Settings > Siri & Spotlight" there is "Delete Siri & Dictation Hisotry" button, but it doesn't seem to be related to this problem, and anyway, I already pressed it.

Also, below, there is "Siri Suggestins & Privacy" button, which allows you to disable suggesting per application. But this didn't help either.


Not possible AFAIK and likely we can not change the order
